# Magento 2 - CMS Specific page_layout XML and Dedicated page_layouts in general?

Tags: layout, css, performance, plugin, page-layouts

I'm looking for some BEST PRACTICES insight into using page_layout.xml. **Is it a good idea to try and decouple the non-shared resources on Product Pages, Category Pages and CMS Pages?** If so, what's the best way to do this? Recently found myself creating a bunch of CMS specific CSS rules for our CSM pages and I knew the CSS rules may continue to grow a bit so I decided to create a dedicated layout file (`Magento_Theme\page_layout\cms_layout.xml`). To achieve this, I created a new page_layout but also had to make a plugin `beforeRenderResult()` to load in in `<body>` BOTH the standard class `page-layout-2columns-left` and the new class `page-layout-cms-layout`. If I didn't do this, I would have had to modify a lot of CSS.

**Some of the benefits I think I'm realizing are:**

- (Maintenance) I no longer have to manage a lot of `Content > Page >
  Design > Layout Update XML` content. I can just change the "Layout" dropdown to the CMS Specific Layout.
- (Slight Performance) I don't have to load the CSS for the CMS pages
  on the Product Pages and Category Pages

Next up - might be to look at some of the heavy UI `JS/CSS` being used on Product Pages and not have that being loaded on Category Pages? Does this situation make sense to experiences Magento Developers OR should I provide more clarity?

I'm pretty certain I'm not making any big performance gains with this particular situation but I am curious whats "Best Practice". As it stands, it seems like Magento load the the entire websites resources on every page, no matter how big or small (`Category JS/CSS`, `Details JS/CSS`, `Checkout JS/CSS`, etc). I'm not sure that's great either.